# If $\sup_n \sum_{k=1}^n P(\vert X_{kn} -a_n\vert > b) \leq c$, then can we find a $d$ such that $\sup_n \sum_{k=1}^n P(\vert X_{nk} \vert > d)\leq c$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

*This is seperate question in itself but I did start as a follow up question to here: [If $\sup_n P(\vert X_n -a_n\vert > b) \leq c$, then can I find a $d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup_n P(\vert X_n \vert > d) \leq c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073057/if-sup-n-p-vert-x-n-a-n-vert-b-leq-c-then-can-i-find-a-d-in-mathbb/4073102#4073102)*

---

Let $\{X_{nk} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, k \leq n \}$ denote a triangular array of real random variables and $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of real numbers. Suppose $\max_k P(\vert X_{nk}\vert>\epsilon) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ for all $\epsilon>0.$

**If $\sup_n \sum_{k=1}^n P(\vert X_{nk} -a_n\vert > b) \leq c$, then can we find a $d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup_n 
 \sum_{k=1}^n  P(\vert X_{nk} \vert > d) \leq c$? And how to choose $d$?**

---

As far as I can tell you need a different solution than the one that Davide provided in the linked question since with $d=\max\{1,d_1,\dots,d_{n_0 -1}\}$ would yield the bound
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n  P(\vert X_{nk} \vert > d) \leq nc
$$
which doesn't give anything useful when applying $\sup_n$ on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_{nk}-a_n|>b)\geq \sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_{nk}|>b+|a_n|)$$

So you get the result immediately if $\sup_n |a_n|<\infty$. However, we *must* have $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|\leq b$.

Indeed, let $|A|>b$. Then, pick $N$ so large that $\max_k P(|X_{nk}|>|A|-b)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for $n\geq N$. Then, for such, $n$, we have

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_{nk}-A|>b)\geq \sum_{k=N}^n P(|X_{nk}-A|>b)\geq \sum_{k=N}^n P(|X_{nk}|< |A|-b)\geq \frac{(n-N)}{2},
$$
from which it immediately follows that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|< b$. But this implies that $\sup_n |a_n|<\infty$ and thus, $d:=b+\sup_n |a_n|$ works.

Comment: Sorry that it took me this long to reply. Thank you for your anwser! There are a few details that I am not sure about: 1) I assume $A$ is $\limsup_n \vert a_n \vert$. Then for the computation to make sense don't you need to know a priori that $\vert A \vert < \infty$. Also the step $\sum_{k=N}^n P(|X_{nk}-A|>b)\geq \sum_{k=N}^n P(|X_{nk}|< |A|-b)$ confuses me a bit. When I try:
$$
\sum_{k=N}^n P(|X_{nk}-A|>b) \geq \sum_{k=N}^n P(|X_{nk}|-|A|>b) = \sum_{k=N}^n P(|X_{nk}|>b+|A|),
$$
so how do you get the minus $-$?

Comment: Multiplying by $-1$ on both sides gives you $-b-\vert A \vert$

Comment: $A$ is not $\limsup_n |a_n|$. $A$ is an arbitrary number outside $[-b,b]$.
 As for the step: The claim is simply that $|X_{nk}|<|A|-b$ implies $|X_{nk}-A|>b$. This follows from the reverse triangle inequality $|x-y|\geq |x|-|y|$, since $|X_{nk}-A|\geq |A|-|X_{n_k}|>|A|-(|A|-b)=b$ where we used our assumption in the second step.

Comment: This step makes sense now! However if $A$ is not $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \vert a_n \vert$ or at least some kind of placeholder then how do get $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \vert a_n \vert < b$ from the computation? Aren't you working towards a contradiction by taking sup on both sides?

Comment: The above proves that $\sum_{k=1}^n P(X_{nk}-A|>b)>c$ for $\frac{n-N}{2}$ sufficiently large uniformly in $|A|\geq |b|+\varepsilon$. This implies that $|A|\geq |a_n|$ for $n$ sufficiently large for any $|A|>b$. It follows that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|<|A|$. Taking the infimum over such $|A|$ gives you \limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|\leq b$.